# Pycharm - Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT) error

Tags: python, pycharm

I am working on a Django project using Pycharm.

I tried to debug the project by setting breakpoints in Pycharm and installed Cython debugger (when Pycharm gave a suggestion).

It worked fine for a few times and suddenly stopped working and started giving the following error.

> Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
>
> Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

But I'm able to debug using `Python pdb`. As it is a big project, I need to type each and every variable name to see their values which is cumbersome.

Is there any issue that's causing this?

BTW, I have gone through this link - https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000409460-Debugging-not-running-on-PyCharm-for-my-Django-project

It was not much helpful.

I suspect that Cython debugger has something to do with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had some issue with **Cython debugger** in **Python virtual environment**.

I just re-created virtual environment and re-installed the requirements and it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

Check your Project Interpreter and chose the right python virtual environment.

Preferences -> Project: Your Project -> Project Interpreter

[image]